# How to check if time is earlier than 12 hours across multiple columns and if so add 12hours

Tags: r, time, data-wrangling

I have a dataset with multiple columns which measured time, but there's inconsistencies in how time was registered, most used a 24h clock whilst others used 12h. I want to convert them all to 24h, by checking whether the time they used is below 12 hours, and if so, add 12 to the time they mentioned. The time is in a character format see below:

```
print(data$T1_Weekdays)
  [1] "20:00" "19:00" "20:00" "19:00" "22:00" "19:00" "20:30" "19:30" "21:30" "21:00" "19:00" "20:00" "20:00" "19:00" "20:45"
 [16] "18:30" "19:45" "19:30" "18:45" "19:30" "20:00" "19:00" "18:45" "19:30" "19:00" "19:30" "18:30" "19:30" "20:00" "20:00"
 [31] "20:00" "21:30" "19:30" "20:00" "20:00" "19:30" "19:00" "18:30" "19:00" "19:00" "20:30" "19:30" "19:00" "19:30" "20:30"
 [46] "19:30" "19:00" "19:30" "19:30" "19:15" "20:00" "19:00" "19:30" "20:00" "21:00" "19:30" "19:30" "19:00" "19:45" "19:30"
 [61] "18:30" "19:45" "20:00" "20:00" "20:00" "18:45" "07:30" "19:45" "20:00" "20:30" "19:30" "21:30" "19:00" "19:45" "19:00"
 [76] "19:30" "19:00" "19:00" "21:30" "20:30" "20:00" "20:30" "07:30" "22:40" "18:45" "19:30" "19:00" "19:00" "19:30" "20:00"


print(data$T1Weekend)
  [1] "20:00" "19:00" "20:15" "19:30" "22:00" "19:00" "21:00" "19:30" "21:30" "21:00" "19:30" "8:00"  "20:00" "19:00" "20:45"
 [16] "18:30" "20:00" "19:30" "19:00" "19:30" "21:30" "19:00" "18:45" "7:30"  "19:00" "19:30" "18:30" "19:30" "20:30" "20:00"
 [31] "20:00" "21:30" "19:30" "20:00" "20:00" "19:45" "19:00" "18:30" "19:00" "19:00" "9:00"  "19:30" "07:00" "19:40" "20:15"
 [46] "20:00" "19:00" "20:15" "7:30"  "20:00" "20:30" "19:00" "19:30" "20:00" "21:00" "19:30" "19:30" "19:00" "19:45" "19:30"
 [61] "18:30" "19:45" "20:00" "20:00" "21:00" "18:45" "20:00" "19:45" "20:00" "20:30" "20:00" "21:30" "19:30" "19:45" "19:00"
 [76] "19:30" "19:00" "7:00"  "21:30" "20:30" "20:00" "20:30" "07:30" "22:40" "18:45" "19:30" "19:00" "19:00" "19:30" "20:30"
 [91] "19:30" "07:30" "19:00" "7:30"  "20:30" "21:30" "20:00" "18:45" "19:30" "20:30" "19:30" "20:30" "20:00" "20:30" "19:00"
```

Is there any way to convert all these character variables to time variables and then check if the time is < 12 hours and add 12 to them in an efficient way? The variables all end in weekdays or  weekend.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert e.g. "07:30" to "19:30"? How could you know "07:30" is AM or PM?

Comment: Just because I know when the question is about PM or AM, so these ones are all about PM, there are some AM ones as well. And yes, I want to convert to 19:30 in time format. Thank you! I know how to do it one at a time, but I wanted to do them all at once since there are many questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `lubridate` package -

```
library(lubridate)
x <- c("20:00", "19:00", "07:30", "7:00")

add_12_hours <- function(time) {
  #convert to period object
  x1 <- hm(time)
  #Add 12 hours if time is less than 12 hours
  x2 <- dplyr::if_else(hour(x1) < 12, x1 + hours(12), x1)
  #Return the output in hh:mm format
  paste(hour(x2), sprintf('%02i', minute(x2)), sep = ":")
}

add_12_hours(x)
#[1] "20:00" "19:00" "19:30" "19:00"
```

---

EDIT - I found a shorter function to do this using `str_replace_all`

```
add_12_hours <- function(time) {
  stringr::str_replace_all(time, '\\d{1,}(?=:\\d{2})', function(m) {
    m <- as.integer(m)
    ifelse(m < 12, m + 12, m)
  })
}

add_12_hours(x)
#[1] "20:00" "19:00" "19:30" "19:00"
```

If you want to apply this to all the columns you may use `across` -

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>% mutate(across(matches('(Weekdays|Weekend)$', add_12_hours)))
```

Comment: Just tried it and for some reason it is not working for me. I need to explore why. Also, is it a time variable at the end? I will need to use these variables to make some subtractions. When I ran it it said: Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @CatM It might be because your dataframe is not called as `data` but something else in your actual code.

Comment: Sorry, I was running my code which was already converting them to time before running your last line, so it was causing an error since it was not in the format I said it would be. Sorry! Thank you for your answer, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

**1) hms** This converts the input to `hms` class, adds 12 hours if it is before noon and then converts to an HH:MM character string. If you prefer an `hms` output then omit the `sub`.  Reproducible test data is in Note at end.

```
library(dplyr)
library(hms)

toPM <- function(x) {
    time <- as_hms(paste0(x, ":00"))
    noon <- as_hms("12:00:00")
    (time + noon * (time < noon)) |> 
      as_hms() |>
      sub(":00$", "", x = _)
}

DF |> mutate(across(c(x, y), toPM))
##       x     y
## 1 21:00 21:00
## 2 12:23 12:23
```

**2) chron times** This uses a similar strategy using chron `times` and is slightly shorter. Omit the `sub` if you prefer a `times` class output.

```
library(chron)
library(dplyr)

toPM <- function(x) {
  time <- times(paste0(x, ":00"))
  (time + 0.5 * (time < 0.5)) |> sub(":..$", "", x = _)
}

DF |> mutate(across(c(x, y), toPM))
##       x     y
## 1 21:00 21:00
## 2 12:23 12:23
```

**3) gsubfn** This uses gsubfn to extract the hours, add 12 if before noon and then insert that back into the wtring:

```
library(gsubfn)

toPM <- function(z) {
   gsubfn("^(..)", ~ as.numeric(h) + 12 * (as.numeric(h) < 12), z)
}
replace(DF, c("x", "y"), lapply(DF[c("x", "y")], toPM))
##       x     y
## 1 21:00 21:00
## 2 12:23 12:23
```

**4) Base R** This splits each time into columns and then adds 12 to the hours if they are less than 12.  No packages are used.

```
toPM <- function(x) {
  with(read.table(text = x, sep = ":", colClasses = c(NA, "character")), 
    paste(V1 + 12 * (V1 < 12), V2, sep = ":"))
}
replace(DF, c("x", "y"), lapply(DF[c("x", "y")], toPM))
##       x     y
## 1 21:00 21:00
## 2 12:23 12:23
```

### Note

```
# test data
x <- c("09:00", "12:23")
DF <- data.frame(x, y = x)
```

Comment: My problem is that I want to do it for multiple columns in a dataframe.

Comment: OK.  Have put the code in a function which can then be applied across selected columns.